# Error on timestamp column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I get this error even though I thought id fixed it can any tell me what wrong with the table please.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
K' at line 22 

CREATE TABLE `dp_confirms` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`newuser` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newpass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`newanswer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`newmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`newfname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newlname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newcompany` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
`newregnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newdrvnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newaddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
`newcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`newcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
`newstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newzip` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
`newphone` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`newfax` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
`sponsor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
`confirm` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
[...]
```

Comment: This is the second question I've seen recently with an error related to `TIMESTAMP(14)` (the other one was [MySQL compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269506/)). Can I ask where you saw an example of using `TIMESTAMP(14)`? I'd like to find out where these are coming from, so I can correct them at the source if I can.

Answer (score 6):

`Timestamp` doesn't have size, remove (14)

Comment: Timestamp does have an optional precision argument, which is a new feature in MySQL 5.6. But the precision can only go up to `(6)`.