# MySQL compatibility

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I have a script that I got online that I wanted to try out. Everything has worked so far except for the last step which is to import a .sql file using phpmyadmin. The .sql script is

```
CREATE TABLE lil_urls (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  url text,
  date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

My server version is 5.5.34-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

The error I get says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) TYPE=MyISAM' at line 4

How do I properly import this file?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this matters but the phpmyadmin version is 4.0.8

Comment: Why do you have a number after `TIMESTAMP`?  What is that supposed to represent?

Comment: I don't know what the 14 is for, that's the way it was when I downloaded it.

Comment: When I removed the number I got this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6`

Comment: `TYPE=` was deprecated a long time ago, and dropped now apparently. Use `ENGINE=MyISAM` instead if you _really_ want `MYISAM` for some reason (there are some valid ones for specific use, but not many), go for `ENGINE=InnoDB` otherwise.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 introduced optional precision for fractional seconds, but the max precision is `(6)`. There is no version of MySQL that allows `TIMESTAMP(14)` so I can't imagine what that was supposed to do.

Comment: I got rid of `(14)` and changed `TYPE=` to `ENGINE=` and that seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Oracle also supports precision for fractional seconds for TIMESTAMP, but the precision value must be in the range from 0 to 9.  A precision of 14 is not supported.

Comment: @user1470242, can I ask where did you download this from? I'm curious what code is trying to use `TIMESTAMP(14)`, and I'd like to correct it at the source if I can. I saw another question today with the same error: [Having a database issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029500/).

Comment: @BillKarwin Weird, nice find. I wonder what this is...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I found http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41510 which says way back in 2008 that TIMESTAMP(14) *stopped* working. It worked but generated deprecation warnings in MySQL 5.0 and 5.1. It seems they made it an error in MySQL 5.5. Now that 5.1 has finally reached end of life, perhaps more people are finally upgrading to 5.5.